# Changing static array

Tags: c, linux, arrays, segmentation-fault, strncpy

I have a static variable declared in a file:

```
static char *msgToUser[] = {
    "MSG1                ", 
    "MSG2                ",
};
```

Inside one of the methods of a class I'm doing this:

```
void InfoUser::ModifyMsg( BYTE msgIdx, char *msgString ){
    strncpy( msgToUser[ idx ], msgString, DISPLAY_SIZE );
}
```

When I do the strncopy the program crashes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array you have defined is an array of pointers to character strings; each character string is a *literal* (ie, a quoted string interpreted as a pointer) - this means it's a *constant*, even if you didn't declare it as such. You cannot modify string literals.

If you want to be able to modify them, you can use an explicit array allocation:

```
// Note: The space padding isn't needed if all you require is that the string
// be able to hold DISPLAY_SIZE characters (incl the null terminator)
static char str_1[DISPLAY_SIZE] = "MSG1                ";
static char str_2[DISPLAY_SIZE] = "MSG1                ";
static char *msgToUser[] = { str_1, str_2 };
```

Comment: In this case, is it even required to initialize them with dummy values? Ain't `static char str_1[SIZE]` enough?

Comment: Indeed it is, in which case the string would be initialized to an empty string (all zeroes). I wasn't sure if the OP wanted the MSG1/MSG2s in, so I left them, but if an initially empty string works that's fine too.

Comment: +1, but I would have gone with `static char msgToUser[][DISPLAY_SIZE] = { "...", "..." };`.

Comment: @schot, the semantics there are slightly different - in particular, you can't use it as a `char **`. It is more convenient to type though.

Answer (score 2):

See C-FAQ. [Question 1.32](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping your array as an array of pointers, make it a two dimensional array of characters which will make it allocate space.

Now, since it is an array of char * and initialization is happening using string literals, when you try to overwrite read only memory of string literals, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined msgToUser as a vector of char-pointers.  These char-pointers point to strings (character arrays) that are stored in memory that has been marked as read-only (In Microsoft's Visual Studio you can change this via a compiler option).

Therefore, if you change this memory, the processor will raise an exception (you are trying to write in read-only memory) and your application will crash.